# Why cannot I create a file in a folder I own with chmod 655, but 755 works?

Tags: ubuntu, chmod

I have a backup folder owned by a system user (mongodb) and chmoded 655. When I try to create files in it, it raises a permission issue:

```
root@maquina:/var/backups/mongodb# su -s /bin/bash mongodb -c "/usr/bin/touch test.txt"
/usr/bin/touch: cannot touch `test.txt': Permission denied
```

Chmoding to 755 enables me to create the file.

I guess I probably need to tweak the privileges (+X ?) but cannot find how.

Can anyone shed some light on this ?

Thank you!

Comment: Why would do you want to have a permission of 655 on a folder you own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have execute permissions in the directory in order to do seeks there. Without being able to do a seek, you can't create a file

```
sudo chmod u+x /var/backups/mogodb
```